# Python Loop Performance too slow

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a number of records that come from database. I want to convert the structure of the DB records to be more like a parent and child class

So `forecast_data` has properties as follows:

```
component_plan_id, region, planning_item, cfg, measure, period_str, currency, forecast_value, forecast_currency
```

The idea is to convert to parent record, with property

```
component_plan_id, region, planning_item, cfg, measure, currency
```

and the child record for each parent record will be

```
period_str, forecast_value, forecast_currency
```

So what I do in my code, is that

```
1. Get the list of unique property in parent's records
2. For each record in (1), get records with the same attribute, create child record with period_str, forecast_value, forecast_currency
```

The code below already works, but somehow it is too slow. Is there any way to enhance the performance?

```
data = []
# Format the forecast data
for rec in list(set((row.component_plan_id, row.region, 
    row.planning_item, row.cfg, row.measure, row.currency) for row in forecast_data)):
    
    new_rec = ComponentForecastReadDto(component_plan_id = rec[0],
        region = rec[1], planning_item = rec[2],
        cfg = rec[3], measure = rec[4], currency = rec[5])

    # Get forecast value
    new_rec.forecast = []
    for rec_forecast in [x for x in forecast_data if 
            x.component_plan_id == new_rec.component_plan_id and
            x.region == new_rec.region and
            x.planning_item == new_rec.planning_item and
            x.cfg == new_rec.cfg and 
            x.measure == new_rec.measure and 
            x.currency == new_rec.currency]:
        new_forecast = ComponentForecastValueReadDto(period_str = rec_forecast.period_str,
            forecast_value = rec_forecast.forecast_value, forecast_currency = rec_forecast.forecast_currency)
        new_rec.forecast.append(new_forecast)

    data.append(new_rec)
```

`ComponentForecastReadDto` and `ComponentForecastValueReadDto` are inherited from `BaseModel` in pydantic.

Sample input:

```
| component_plan id  | region  | planning_item | cfg   | measure | period_str | currency | forecast_value | forecast_currency |
| 1                  | America | Item 1        | cfg A | unit    | 2022-06    | 2        | 100            | 200               |
| 1                  | America | Item 1        | cfg A | unit    | 2022-07    | 2        | 150            | 300               |
| 1                  | America | Item 1        | cfg A | unit    | 2022-08    | 2        | 200            | 400               |
| 1                  | Asia    | Item 1        | cfg A | unit    | 2022-06    | 3        | 150            | 450               |
```

Output

Record #1

```
component_plan_id = 1
region = America
planning_item = Item 1
cfg = cfg A
measure = unit
currency = 2

children:
     1. period_str = 2022-06
        forecast_value = 100
        forecast_currency = 200
     2. period_str = 2022-07
        forecast_value = 150
        forecast_currency = 300
     3. period_str = 2022-08
        forecast_value = 200
        forecast_currency = 400
```

Record #2

```
component_plan_id = 1
region = Asia
planning_item = Item 1
cfg = cfg A
measure = unit
currency = 3

children:
     1. period_str = 2022-06
        forecast_value = 150
        forecast_currency = 450
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: It doesn't look as though there are issues with the loop as such. It's more likely that the majority of time is spent in ComponentForecastReadDto and ComponentForecastValueReadDto. That's probably where you should be looking for efficiencies. In the meantime, put some timers around the calls to those functions to find out exactly how long they're taking

Comment: @MinhDao I've added the sample data and output

Comment: @AlbertWinestein ComponentForecastReadDto and ComponentForecastValueReadDto is just object creation assigning value to it in the constructor, no other computation is done. Each record creation can take 0.01 secs, but due to the number of records which is in thousands, this become almost a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the function like follows:

1. Sort the list based on parent's property.
2. Loop through the records, create child record accordingly. If the attribute is different, create another parent record.

This reduces the running time from O(N^2) to O(N log N), it runs really fast.

```
forecast_data = sorted(forecast_data, key = lambda x: (x.component_plan_id, x.region, x.planning_item, x.cfg, x.measure, x.currency))
data = []

if (len(forecast_data) > 0):
    cur_component_plan_id = forecast_data[0].component_plan_id
    cur_region = forecast_data[0].region
    cur_planning_item = forecast_data[0].planning_item
    cur_cfg = forecast_data[0].cfg
    cur_measure = forecast_data[0].measure
    cur_currency = forecast_data[0].currency

    new_rec = ComponentForecastReadDto(component_plan_id = cur_component_plan_id,
        region = cur_region, planning_item = cur_planning_item,
        cfg = cur_cfg, measure = cur_measure, currency = cur_currency)            

    # Format the forecast data
    for rec in forecast_data:
        if (rec.component_plan_id != cur_component_plan_id or rec.region != cur_region or
            rec.planning_item != cur_planning_item or rec.cfg != cur_cfg or
            rec.measure != cur_measure or rec.currency != cur_currency):

            data.append(new_rec)

            cur_component_plan_id = rec.component_plan_id
            cur_region = rec.region
            cur_planning_item = rec.planning_item
            cur_cfg = rec.cfg
            cur_measure = rec.measure
            cur_currency = rec.currency
            new_rec = ComponentForecastReadDto(component_plan_id = cur_component_plan_id,
                region = cur_region, planning_item = cur_planning_item,
                cfg = cur_cfg, measure = cur_measure, currency = cur_currency)
            
        new_forecast = ComponentForecastValueReadDto(period_str = rec.period_str,
            forecast_value = rec.forecast_value, forecast_currency = rec.forecast_currency)
        new_rec.forecast.append(new_forecast)

    data.append(new_rec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in CSV format, with name `input.csv`:

```
component_plan_id,region,planning_item,cfg,measure,period_str,currency,forecast_value,forecast_currency
1,America,Item1,cfgA,unit,2022-06,2,100,200
1,America,Item1,cfgA,unit,2022-07,2,150,300
1,America,Item1,cfgA,unit,2022-08,2,200,400
1,Asia,Item1,cfgA,unit,2022-06,3,150,450
```

I used `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` to rewrite this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

GROUP_COLUMNS = [
    'component_plan_id',
    'region',
    'planning_item',
    'cfg',
    'measure',
    'currency'
]
CHILD_COLUMNS = [
    'period_str',
    'forecast_value',
    'forecast_currency'
]

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

groups = df.groupby(GROUP_COLUMNS)

results = []

for name, group in groups:
    record = dict()
    for i in range(len(GROUP_COLUMNS)):
        record[GROUP_COLUMNS[i]] = name[i]
    record['children'] = group[CHILD_COLUMNS].to_dict(orient='records')
    results.append(record)

pprint(results)
```

In case you want it faster, `joblib` Parallel might help a bit:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


GROUP_COLUMNS = [
    'component_plan_id',
    'region',
    'planning_item',
    'cfg',
    'measure',
    'currency'
]
CHILD_COLUMNS = [
    'period_str',
    'forecast_value',
    'forecast_currency'
]


def handle(name, group):
    record = dict()
    for i in range(len(GROUP_COLUMNS)):
        record[GROUP_COLUMNS[i]] = name[i]
    record['children'] = group[CHILD_COLUMNS].to_dict(orient='records')
    return record


df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
groups = df.groupby(GROUP_COLUMNS)

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
    delayed(handle)(name, group) for name, group in groups
)

pprint(results)
```

Both ways will return the same result:

```
[
    {
        'cfg': 'cfgA',
        'children': [
            {'forecast_currency': 200,
             'forecast_value': 100,
             'period_str': '2022-06'},
            {'forecast_currency': 300,
             'forecast_value': 150,
             'period_str': '2022-07'},
            {'forecast_currency': 400,
             'forecast_value': 200,
             'period_str': '2022-08'}
        ],
        'component_plan_id': 1,
        'currency': 2,
        'measure': 'unit',
        'planning_item': 'Item1',
        'region': 'America'
    },
    {
        'cfg': 'cfgA',
        'children': [
            {'forecast_currency': 450,
             'forecast_value': 150,
             'period_str': '2022-06'}
        ],
        'component_plan_id': 1,
        'currency': 3,
        'measure': 'unit',
        'planning_item': 'Item1',
        'region': 'Asia'
    }
]
```

Comment: sounds interesting! but I have already done it in my way to optimize the running time from Big O perspective. yours may work as well, but still need to convert the arrays to objects as well.